# Spark - How to read multiple files as DataFrames in parallel?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I have a defined list of S3 file paths and I want to read them as DataFrames:

```py
ss = SparkSession(sc)
JSON_FILES = ['a.json.gz', 'b.json.gz', 'c.json.gz']
dataframes = {t: ss.read.json('s3a://bucket/' + t) for t in JSON_FILES}
```

The code above works, but in an unexpected way. When the code is submitted to a Spark cluster, only a single file is read at time, keeping only a single node occupied.

Is there a more efficient way to read multiple files? A way to make all nodes work at the same time?

---

More details:

- PySpark - Spark 2.2.0
- Files stored on S3
- Each file contains one JSON object per line
- The files are compressed, as it can be seen by their extensions

Comment: you want to load all the files which exist in bucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was: I didn't understand Spark's runtime architecture. Spark has the notion of "workers", which, if I now understand it better (don't trust me), are capable of doing stuff in parallel. When we submit a Spark job, we can set both things, the number of workers and the level of parallelism they can leverage.

If you are using the Spark command `spark-submit`, these variables are represented as the following options:

- `--num-executors`: similar to the notion of number of workers
- `--executor-cores`: how many CPU cores a single worker should use

[This](https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/distribution_of_executors_cores_and_memory_for_spark_application.html) is a document that helped me understand these concepts and how to tune them.

Coming back to my problem, in that situation I would have one worker per file.

Answer (score 0):

To read multiple inputs in Spark, use wildcards. That's going to be true whether you're constructing a dataframe or an rdd.

```
ss = SparkSession(sc)

dataframes = ss.read.json("s3a://bucket/*.json.gz")
```

Comment: But this give me a single DataFrame, right? The JSON files should represent different tables/DataFrames.